# VB6: get onreadystate value from browser control

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control, onreadystatechange

I'm trying to get the `onreadystate` value from the browser control do detect when the page has finished loading. Unfortunately, the event's `.returnValue` gets returned empty.

Here's my code:

```
Dim WithEvents m_doc As HTMLDocument

Private Sub Form_Load()
    Set m_doc = WebBrowser1.Document
End Sub

Private Sub m_doc_onreadystatechange()
Dim m_event As IHTMLEventObj
    Set m_event = m_doc.parentWindow.event
    m_value = "'" & m_event.returnValue & "'"
    MsgBox "onreadystatechange: " & m_value
End Sub
```

Any ideas on what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the HTMLDocument's events try

```
m_doc.createDocumentFromUrl "http://www.microsoft.com", ""
```

Otherwise you can use the WebBrowser control's event to detect when a document is completely loaded or call the Navigate or Navigate2 method and immediately loop while polling the WebBrowser.ReadyState

```
WebBrowse1.Navigate2 "http://www.microsoft.com"
Do While WebBrowser1.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop
```

Of course don't forget to add an error handler.